# simple PHP signup form wont POST to MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm very new to this, I made a php to test the connection with the database and it seems fine, but writing information to a table isn't working.

Heres the index.php (where the signup form is)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<form action="signup.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"><br>
 <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname"><br>
 <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username"><br>
 <input type="text" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"><br>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Heres the signup.php (which is what i think might be broken)

```html
<?php

include 'dbh.php';

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO useraccounts (firstname, lastname, uid, pwd) 
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$uid', '$pwd')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

and heres the dbh.php which connects to mysql

```html
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "databasename");


if (!$conn) {
 die("Connection failed: ".mysql_connect_error());
}

?>
```

I'm sure there's already a load of questions like mine out there but I'm so new to this I'm finding it hard to learn from the answers I've come across

Comment: Any error or something?

Comment: It's an off-topic typo >>> `mysql_connect` and `mysql_connect_error`. Add an `i` to that and have fun.

Comment: Take a look at `mysqli_error()`.  There could be errors coming from the database that this code is simply ignoring.  Also, take a look at prepared statements and query parameters.  Currently this code is *wide open* to SQL injection and you could literally be trying to execute *anything* on your database.

Comment: no errors unfortunately

Comment: on top of what's been said; and I deleted my comment about this earlier... used as `http://localhost` or `file:///`? or hosted?

Comment: and don't store plain text passwords along with your not using a prepared statement; you will get hacked

Comment: localhost i think Fred -i-   Its writing to the table fine now, although all this talk about hacking and SQL injection is scaring me

Comment: You should really change your pwd input field to be of type `password`. As @Fred-ii- pointed out, don't store passwords in plain text. Use something like [`bcrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: @Burnsy: As well it should.  This code is clearly a learning experience, and that's good.  Please take a look at things like "SQL injection" and "password hashing" to continue with that learning experience.  **Do not** use this code to handle *actual* user passwords in an *actual* live system.

Comment: it should scare you, that way you won't use that code in a live site.

Comment: oh! yes I was planning on encrypting password, just had bare bones to see if it was writing to the database.

Comment: encrypting and hashing are two different animals.

Comment: @Burnsy you will also need validate your form inputs and prevent SQL injections, there is some info about [form validation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp) and [avoiding SQL injections using prepare()](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291215/1818267)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your signup.php you use the following line (**mysqli**):

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

However in your dbh.php you use (**mysql**):

```
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "databasename");
```

And

```
mysql_connect_error());
```

Other than that I can't see anything else what could be wrong.
Your query seems correct and you declare your post data.

I suggest you try to look for error messages if the solution above doesnt provide anything.

Comment: that's already been said in comments, and added something much better than this.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it, thankyou

Comment: @Burnsy: If this answer works for you, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try quote you columns with => `